# Constexpr class c++

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

I'm trying to create a class that is constructed at compile time and then can be used, of course without any method that modifies it.
I'm new with the keywords `static` and `constexpr`, so probably I'm not using them properly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename unsigned_integer, unsigned_integer max_n>
class ClassicSieve {
  private:
    static array<bool, max_n+1> prime;
    //unsigned_integer max_n;
  public:
    constexpr ClassicSieve() {
      // 1 is not prime
      prime[1] = false;
      // even numbers
      for(unsigned_integer i = 4; i <= max_n; i+=2) {
        prime[i] = false;
      }
      // all the others
      for (unsigned_integer p = 3; p*p <= max_n; p++) {
        if (prime[p]) {
          for(unsigned_integer j = 2*p; j <= max_n; j+=p) {
            prime[j] = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    inline bool is_prime(unsigned_integer n) {
      return prime[n];
    }
};

int main() {
  constexpr auto s = ClassicSieve<unsigned int, 10000000>();
  cout << s.is_prime(2) << endl;
  cout << s.is_prime(3) << endl;
  cout << s.is_prime(4) << endl;
  cout << s.is_prime(5) << endl;
  cout << s.is_prime(6700417) << endl;
}
```

Once `max_n` is fixed all the computation needed can be evaluated at compile-time, so for sure, it can be possible to do what I'm trying.
The method `is_prime` just read the data_member `prime` without modifying it.

When I  compile I get:

```
note: a constant expression cannot modify an object that is visible outside that expression
```

referred to the constructor. I see that this is a problem in general, but in my case I won't modify the object anymore. How  can I tell it  to the compiler?

Comment: Don't make the member static.

Comment: `is_prime` should be `const` too.

Comment: Your `prime` array is not initialized, and has no `true`.

Comment: `10'000'000` doesn't necessary fit in `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Monica why shouldn't use static?

Comment: User handles mentions are prefix based. You don't ping *me* if you just use "Monica". As for why not use static, because you are "initializing" the wrong object that way. You c'tor initializes the *local* `s`, not the static member. It tries to modify the static member when its run, but that is not without its problems since a static member doesn't belong to any particular instance. When the variable is not static, it becomes a part of the actual object being initialized (`s`).

Answer (score 4):

There are many issues with this code:

- Your `std::array` is uninitialized, and only some values are set to `false` afterwards; you need to initialize all values to `true`
- You'll want to mark `is_prime` `const`
- You are trying to allocate (and loop) 10 million elements at compile-time, which is outside most compiler limits (you'll need to find the appropriate flag for your compiler to increment that limit)

  - most (all?) implementations of `std::array` attempt to perform stack-allocation, and this will take up a significant amount of that
- (minor) You don't need to declare `is_prime` to be `inline`; it already is by virtue of being defined in the class declaration

Here's an implementation that will do the trick (I've restricted the size to 10 instead of 10 million):

```
template<typename unsigned_integer, unsigned_integer max_n>
class ClassicSieve {
  private:
    static constexpr const std::array<bool, max_n+1> prime = ClassicSieve::init_primes();
    static constexpr auto init_primes()
    {
        std::array<bool, max_n+1> prime{};
        prime.fill(true);
        // 1 is not prime
        prime[1] = false;
        // even numbers
        for(unsigned i = 4; i <= max_n; i+=2) {
            prime[i] = false;
        }
        // all the others
        for (unsigned p = 3; p*p <= max_n; p++) {
            if (prime[p]) {
                for(unsigned j = 2*p; j <= max_n; j+=p) {
                    prime[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }
  public:
    bool is_prime(unsigned_integer n) const {
      return prime[n];
    }
};
```

(*This code assumes at least a 32 bit unsigned integer)

Usage:

```
constexpr auto s = ClassicSieve<unsigned int, 10>();
std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.is_prime(2) << std::endl; // true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.is_prime(3) << std::endl; // true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.is_prime(4) << std::endl; // false
std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.is_prime(5) << std::endl; // true
```

#### [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6683o5csr)

Comment: @L.A.: You can move the free function inside the class as static member function.

Comment: @L.A. Sure, I just seem to like it this way. I'm not a fan of private static member functions;  they clutter the class IMHO. I've updated the answer to reflect your request.

Comment: @L.A. - you can modify the `prime` array inside the body of the constructor, as `init_primes()` does, but you *must* initialize it before, or with a default in the variable declaration (for example: `std::array<bool, max_n+1> prime {};` (I mean: the final `{}`)) or in the initialization list of the constructor (for example: `ClassicSieve () : prime{} { /* here you can modify prime */ }`).

Comment: @L.A. - Anyway... you can isn't you should. An additional function (internal or external) has the additional advantage that can be reused for different constructors.

Comment: @L.A. - Frankly, I don't know the reason. I only know that "for the [constexpr] constructor of a class or struct, every base class sub-object and every non-variant non-static data member must be initialized" (see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). Now I see that this rule is signed as "until C++20"... maybe this rule is relaxed and, starting from C++20, an initialization isn't required anymore.